# Parsing MIT format binary data produced with DATAQ instrument

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to parse in binary data produced from measurements of the membrane potential of a squid giant axon which I found [here](https://physionet.org/content/sgamp/1.0.0/). My aim is to model the data using a nonlinear VAR (NVAR) model, however I'm struggling to find a resource which explains the MIT format they quote the data as being in:

> The files in the raw directory contain the original raw values captured by the DATAQ Instruments capturing device (translated into MIT format). Both channels are given in volts, and have not been calibrated or translated into their physical units.

So far I've attempted to use `numpy.fromfile` and reading the data in using:

```py
with open(filename, "rb") as file:
    ...
```

and attempting to decode it with a mixture of different codecs. The numpy method gave floating point values back, unfortunately they were nonsensical. The decoding didn't work for any of the codecs I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this Python package from the MIT Laboratory for Computational Physiology](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/wfdb-python/tree/main) that seems to be specifically meant to process that kind of data.

[This notebook](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/wfdb-python/blob/main/demo.ipynb) demonstrates the functionalities of the library.

Comment: Yeah, I just found their reference page about an hour ago. I've been fighting with the install for the C libraries because I've built my model in C++ and I'd prefer to decompress the files on the fly, then remove the decompressed file after finishing using it. At the moment, I'm probably just going to write a python script to handle it, then add it as a pre-build task in my CMakeLists.txt.